# using php class object like associative array

Tags: php, class, associative-array

so i'm having this class:

```
class c_user
{
    function __construct($userID)
    {
        dbOpen($db); // open database
        $sq = "select * from users where user_id='".$userID."'";
        $rs = getRS($sq, $db); // query database - simplified
        $this->firstname = $rs['firstname'];
    }
}
```

i'm using it like this:

```
$user = new c_user(123);
echo $user->firstname;
```

is it possible accessing data as associative array? like that:

```
echo $user['firstname'];
```

thanks

Answer (score 3):

It is, you just have to make your class implement the [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) interface.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
class c_user 
{
    function __construct($userid)
    {
        $rs = array('firstname'=>'myfirstname');
        $this->firstname = $rs['firstname'];
    }
}

$user = new c_user(123);
//echo $user->firstname;
$user =  (array) $user;
echo $user['firstname'];
```